# Iterating a list in AWS Lambda Function for Email Template using Python HTML

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, email, templates, aws-lambda

I'm building an email body using AWS lambda_function in Python. I've created html template that is provided below. I'm calling to MySQL Data base to get the data using python. I need to pass the data to the template to populate them in email body - iterating that list in a table. How can I pass it from Python Lambda_function so that I can display as shown below.

QA: I'm new to Python and AWS Lambda_function integration. Can you please show me how to pass record to sendemail and dynamically populate data in html table rows. Looking for code level solution, it would be great if you could help. Please feel free to modify the HTML template and Python code as necessary. Thanks.

This is my What I need to build - [image]

Here is my HTML Template for Table

```
<tr>
    <td style="padding:35px 70px 30px;" class="em_padd" valign="top" align="center" bgcolor="#f6f7f8">
        <table width="100%%" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="10" border="1" align="center">
            <tbody>
                <tr style="font-weight: bold">
                    <td>Ticker</td>
                    <td>Order Type</td>
                    <td>Creation Units</td>
                    <td>Authorized Participant</td>
                    <td>Payment Type</td>
                    <td>Settlement Date</td>
                    <td>Restricted Securities</td>
                </tr>
                <% var value; for value in list{ %>
                <tr>
                    <td>%(value.ticker)s</td>
                    <td>%(value.orderType)s</td>
                    <td>%(value.creationUnits)d</td>
                    <td>%(value.ap)s</td>
                    <td>%(value.paymentType)s</td>
                    <td>%(value.settlementDate)s</td>
                    <td>%(value.rs)s</td>
                </tr>
          }%>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
```

Here is lambda_function.py

```
import json
import fund_contacts
import client_agreement_contacts
import boto3
import os
import mysql.connector
from mysql.connector import Error
import json
from datetime import datetime

def sendemail(template_name, toAddr, subject, data):
    sns_client = boto3.client(
        'sns',
        region_name=os.environ['REGION'],
        aws_access_key_id=os.environ['ACCESS_KEY_ID'],
        aws_secret_access_key=os.environ['SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'],
    )
    message = {
        "tmpl_id": template_name,
        "to_email": toAddr,
        "subject": subject,
        "data": data
    }
    # Send Event
    sns_client.publish(
        TargetArn=os.environ['EMAIL_ARN'], Message=json.dumps(message))


def getOrderSummary():
    try:
        mySQLConnection = mysql.connector.connect(host='asbc.ueue.rds.amazonaws.com',
                                                  database='QA',
                                                  user='abcd',
                                                  password='random@1')

        cursor = mySQLConnection.cursor(buffered=True)
        sql_select_query = """SELECT    ord.ticker           AS 'Ticker', 
                                ord.transaction_type AS 'Order Type', 
                                ord.unit_quantity    AS 'Creation Units', 
                                apf.legal_name       AS 'Authorized Participant', 
                                ord.payment_method   AS 'Payment Type', 
                                ord.settlement 'Settlement Date', 
                                'No' AS 'Restricted Securities' 
                                FROM      ETP_QA.order ord 
                                LEFT JOIN ETP_QA.apfirm apf 
                                ON        ord.apfirm = apf.id 
                                WHERE     order_time > Curdate() - INTERVAL 1 DAY """
        cursor.execute(sql_select_query)
        record = cursor.fetchall()

        #my_json_string = json.dumps(record)
        # print(my_json_string)

        return record

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to get record from MySQL table: {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if (mySQLConnection.is_connected()):
            cursor.close()
            mySQLConnection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")


def lambda_handler(event, context):
    if 'Records' in event:
        message = json.loads(event['Records'][0]['Sns']['Message'])
    else:
        message = event

    records = getOrderSummary()

    if not records:
        templateName = 'ORDER_SUMMARY_NO_DATA'
    else:
        templateName = 'ORDER_SUMMARY_DATA'

    for row in records:
        print("Ticker = ", row[0], )
        print("Order Type = ", row[1])  
        print("Creation Units = ", row[2])
        print("Authorized Participant  = ", row[3])
        print("Settlement Date = ", row[4], )
        print("Restricted Securities = ", row[5], "\n")

    recipient_list = 'SomeEmail@gmail.com'
    current_time = datetime.now()
    subject = 'ABC Investment Series Trust Trade Recap -' + current_time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y')

    # How to set the message so I can itegrate them as per Email Template? 
    # message = records 
    sendemail(templateName, recipient_list, subject, message)
```

This is what data set that I'm getting from database looks like -

```
Ticker =  BTAL
Order Type =  Create
Creation Units =  1
Authorized Participant  =  Hamlin AP Firm
Settlement Date =  Cash
Restricted Securities =  T+1

Ticker =  CFA
Order Type =  Create
Creation Units =  1
Authorized Participant  =  Hamlin AP Firm
Settlement Date =  Cash
Restricted Securities =  T+1

Ticker =  SSUS
Order Type =  Create
Creation Units =  1
Authorized Participant  =  Hamlin AP Firm
Settlement Date =  Cash
Restricted Securities =  T+1

Ticker =  TPHDE
Order Type =  Create
Creation Units =  2
Authorized Participant  =  Hamlin AP Firm
Settlement Date =  Inkind
Restricted Securities =  T+1
```

Comment: Use a template engine such as jinja2.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry for the confusion. Actually question was not template engine but how to pass data to template. Specially this line - sendemail(templateName, recipient_list, subject, message). How can I set the records to message so it populates data to html template as per screen shot.

Comment: It's a **lambda** function - yes, l-a-m-**b-d**-a - not just "lamda" ....

Comment: Sorry marc_s. You're correct - lambda. Totally new to this. Can you please help?

Comment: If I understand what you're trying to do ... you use a template engine. You create a template, which will be a minimally modified version of the HTML template that you've shown, then you pass the template and the message to the template engine, it will insert the various properties of the message into the template, and return you a string (with the final HTML). That's your message to send.

Comment: Exactly! I got pretty much everything in place. Only portion that I'm struggling to figure out how to pass the data to template setting those properties so that properties gets replaced by real data set that I attached.  Here is an example how a single property gets replaced with real data in template : message['apfirm_name'] = "ASCD Firm" But I'm not able to find an easy solution how to pass a list so it derives expected table output in screen shot.